# Cannot find protocol declaration for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, xcode, protocols, declaration

Something weird happened to my app. All was working the other night but now when I load in xcode i get 'Cannot find protocol declaration for NSFetchedResultsController' error in my application.h file for the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@class DBRestClient; @interface DartScorerAppDelegate: NSObject <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate> {
```

I haven't changed anything in this code. I've tried cleaning, unlinking the framework and reimporting, taking out the references to all the code files and reimporting them, but nothing  clears this error message. It's affecting all instances of the NSFetchedResultsController and I'm out of ideas on how to resolve it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's in your prefix header?

Comment: #import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_3_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iPhone SDK 3.0 and later."
#endif


#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#endif

Comment: do you use git or other source control? try reverting to a version of your project that worked and look for differences.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this. My issue was that I simply forgot to import `<CoreData/CoreData.h>`. In your case, maybe it's a bug? Try deleting that line and reimporting it relying on the autofill.